# Changing OpenID is broken on Data Explorer

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

To reproduce:

1. Go to [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com) and sign in.
2. From your profile, hit up "change openid" and provide some new credentials. (I was trying to go from SE OpenID to Google.)
3. Something dies with the boring generic error below and the change doesn't go through.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Runtime Error
>
> Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current
>   custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the
>   application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons).
>   It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server
>   machine.
>
> Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be
>   viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within
>   a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the
>   current web application. This  tag should then have its
>   "mode" attribute set to "Off".
>
> ```
> <!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->
>
> <configuration>
>     <system.web>
>         <customErrors mode="Off"/>
>     </system.web>
> </configuration>
> ```
>
> Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a
>   custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the
>   application's  configuration tag to point to a custom
>   error page URL.
>
> ```
> <!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->
>
> <configuration>
>     <system.web>
>         <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
>     </system.web>
> </configuration>
> ```

Comment: I can't reproduce this (switched from OpenID to Yahoo). That error message is designed to tell you nothing, by the way.

Comment: @Asad I'm aware that it's designed to tell me nothing. I'm just saying that that's where the relative helpfulness of my report drops right off. But thanks for the no-repro note... :) I updated the post with the specific OpenIDs involved.

Comment: Yup, that breaks it.

Comment: Reproduced, checking...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, that was....yeah. Sorry about that. Fixed in the next revision > 2012.9.7.6.

In the near future the goal is to directly support multiple OpenID providers like the main network does, so the relevant code will get some further cleanup when that happens.